# How can I change an element when a class is applied to a separate element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I need a little js help. I want to change my nav background color -- see the bottom here: http://momentum-demo.squarespace.com  -- based on the active slide. The gallery js assigns a class of .sqs-active-slide to the active slide.

Basically:

If #yui_3_17_2_1_1433961025758_314 has the class .sqs-active-slide, set the background-color of #headerWrapper to #ccc

And run it again every time the slide changes.

I'm proficient in jQuery and YUI but haven't had to dabble in it for a couple years. This one has got me stumped. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you let the hyperlink to the code in the question  but did not used it, it's avaialble only when editting your post

Answer (score 1):

You could run a code snippet on a timer to check and make a change:

```
var check = $('#yui_3_17_2_1_1433961025758_314'),
    menu = $('#headerWrapper');
window.setInterval(function(){
  menu.toggleClass('sqs-active-slide', check.hasClass('sqs-active-slide'));
}, 1000);  /runs every 1 second
```

The best way would be to tie in to the plugins own `event`s:

```
var check = $('#yui_3_17_2_1_1433961025758_314'),
    menu = $('#headerWrapper');

$(document).on('onSlideChange', function(){  //or whatever the event is.
  menu.toggleClass('sqs-active-slide', check.hasClass('sqs-active-slide'));
});
```

Your CSS:

```
.classtochangeBG { background-color:#ccc; }
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, this is super helpful! Two things that may or may not cause a conflict: my slideshow is set to change every 10 seconds, but the user can also click on an arrow to manually switch to the next slide.

What do you think? Will that be an issue?

Comment: +1, except I'd recommend not using the ID of the slide: in my experience with Squarespace those are likely to be auto-generated and will change. If there are classes, it'd be better to use those, although if that's not specific enough you might also have to work the parent elements into the selector as well.

Comment: Ah right, the IDs that start yui_ typically change. Blerg. This may be more trouble than it is worth. I'll keep experimenting, thanks for the help!

Comment: Rummaging through the site code I think there are onSlideChange and afterSlideChange events you can tap into.

Comment: Apparently you can tie into the events mentioned by @Moss.  That would be the best way to do this.  The event fires whether the slide moves automatically or manually.

Comment: Updated code to include event name and simplified the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the update -- don't think toggleClass is going to work here because I have multiple slides and want different colors for each.

Comment: Also doesn't look like onSlideChange or afterSlideChange work here. I tried just popping an alert and nothing happened. Bummer.

Thanks for your help, everyone. There's just too many events in the gallery for me to sort out where and when my js needs to fire. :(